# Finding Mouse click position in IconView in GTK

Tags: python, gtk

I am building a file browser using `Gtk.IconView` in python. I am trying to find the path of an icon selected using " selection-changed" signal using `gtk.IconView.get_path_at_pos(x,y)`.

The docs are mum on how to obtain the `(x,y)`. How do I find them?

using python 2.7 and pygtk 2.24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `get_path_at_pos`. It is meant for cases where you handle the button presses directly (which you should avoid unless you really have good reasons to do so).

Simply use `gtk_icon_view_get_selected_items` (C) or the pygtk equivalent `iconview.get_selected_items()` which gives you a list (in C a `GList`) of currently selected `Gtk.TreePath`s which is what you desire.